# Why Custom contact form 7 returns empty content?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I use this contact form 7 to generate a bit more custom form but on the test that I did, I get a mail without the content. How can I solve this issue?

```
<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text text-207 "weekly demo"] </label>

<label> Role Within the Company </label>
 <p>[checkbox RoleInCompany "Business" "Technology" "Strategy"] </br>


[submit "Send"]
```

The content of the received email:

```
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]

-- 
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on  (http://bbbb.com)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have removed [your-subject] and [your-message] shortcodes from your template.
Add your custom shortcodes via "MAIL" tab.

[image]

It should look like this:

```
From: <[your-email]>
Subject: [text-207]

Name:
[your-name]

Role in Company:
[RoleInCompany]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to change the message body in "E-mail" such like this.

```
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message:
[your-message]

-- 
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on  (http://bbbb.com)
```

If you are using multilingual pages, you should confirm that you have linked the correct contact form.